# Changing the background color of only one UITabBarItem

Tags: swift, swift2, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to create a look like Instragram's old tabbar, where the middle tab button was the "upload" button ([old tabbar pictured on top](http://d3lp4xedbqa8a5.cloudfront.net/s3/digital-cougar-assets/Cosmo/2016/05/12/78211/edited-toolbar-(1).jpg)). After clicking this the tab bar gets hidden and you're taken to an upload screen where you can then cancel out of via a button on the top left. How could I create a different colored background around just one tabbar item?

Would it even be a tabbar item or would be be a button laid over the middle position in the tabbar which takes you to a modal segue?

Answer (score 0):

You can access UIView of each tabbar item by `UITabBarController.tabBar.subviews[index]`. Index in this case is 1 based - e.g. first tab is 1. Obviously when you get UIView you can set the background color.

Comment: how would I go about accessing `TabBar`? `UITabBar` has no `.subviews[]` and when I try to connect from storyboard to my TabBarController.swift I get `Getter for 'tabBar' with Objective-C selector 'tabBar' conflicts with getter for 'tabBar' from superclass 'UITabBarController' with the same Objective-C selector` and `Property 'tabBar' with type 'UITabBar!' cannot override a property with type 'UITabBar'`

Comment: @TommyK from your ViewController of the TabBar you should be able to access TabBar (I use Xamarin so I am not sure how it is capitlized in XCode, probably it is just tabBar).

Comment: @TommyK, you can access tabBar from UITabBarController, I'll update the answer to be more clear https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/

Comment: @TommyK and UITabBar inherits from (or in swift terminology is a subclass of) UIView, so it has subviews, as UIView has them.

Comment: Still not working for me. When I select UITabBarController, the only options after it are all methods `tabBar(self: UITabBarController)`, there is no just `.tabBar.subviews`. If I try to enter what you wrote I get `Ambiguous reference to member 'tabBar(_:didSelectItem:)'`

Comment: @TommyK I have just checked in XCode, I am not aware how you create code behind for UITabBar, but in FirstViewController.swift in the default tab app template you can enter (parentViewController as! UITabBarController).tabBar without the problem. Clearly if there was TabBarController.swift you could do that even more simply, but I am not an expert for XCode as said.